# Javascript content type being changed after URL Rewrite

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I am trying to do Reverse Proxy with ARR and URL rewrite to achieve below redirection:

- Source: http://localhost/test
- Destination: http://localhost:83/

The final URL displayed will be same as the source URL.

Redirection works fine, however all my JavaScript files are getting converted to `content-type text/html` instead of `application/javascript` when browsed externally.  This results in a blank page instead of actual functionality.

Rewrite rule:

```
<rules>
...
  <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:83/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="IsJavascript">
    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" customTags="" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:83/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}:{HTTP_HOST}/{R:2}" />
  </rule>
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="IsJavascript">
      <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/javascript" />
    </preCondition>
  </preConditions>      
</outboundRules>
```

The destination page uses AJAX functionality and since the js files are corrupted with random html tags, causing AJAX functions to fail.  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured the issue was due to relative paths in the destination application. Once proxied, the js, css and other links were redirecting to a custom 404 error page which is a part of source application. I have fixed the issue by modifying the code.